# How can I use adjacent sibling selectors with "this" in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a list of various `div`s all with the same class. I am using the `.each` function to select individual ones on the user click (just as an example), and any actions after that naturally require `this`, so that it only selects the div in question. For example:

```
   $(".div").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
               $(this).css("background","green");  
        });
    });
```

But what if I wanted to make the next element in line turn green as well on the click? My first instinct would be to use [adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) but it appears that only works when using two absolute elements, i.e. `$(".element1 + .element2")`. I can't seem to get it to work with `this`.

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naad8wbr/) with a full example to play around with.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need `.each()`. Event binding methods automatically loop over all the elements that match the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `$(this).next()`

http://api.jquery.com/next/

http://jsfiddle.net/naad8wbr/3/

```
$(".div").click(function () {
    $(this).next().css("background", "green");
});
```

If you want both the next and this, then you could use:

```
$(".div").click(function () {
    $(this).next().andSelf().css("background", "green");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/

http://jsfiddle.net/naad8wbr/4/

Comment: This will only do the next one, not the current one as well. "But what if I wanted to make the next element in line turn green *as well* on the click?"

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5cfmnzmb/)***

In order to "make the next element in line turn green as well on the click" you will have to add to the set of elements in the jQuery object.

You can use [nextElementSibling <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling) in correlation with jQuery's [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
 $(this).add(this.nextElementSibling).css("background", "green");
```

Comment: Its not the jQuery way. I.e. `$(this).next()`. And doesn't support old IE. Also it is more verbose. And lastly it doesn't work like the `+` selector as it selects both. The adjacent sibling selector only selects the later of the 2 elements.

Comment: @Petah - Support for IE8 is deprecated (even in the current jQuery versions). `.next()` will not work here because the OP wants **both**.

Comment: The example uses jQuery 1.11 which supports IE 8